# Nesting [su-column] inside [row] to get them to align neatly

Tags: wordpress, alignment, multiple-columns, shortcode, photo-gallery

i built a page to display content using columns stacked on top of each other (with shortcodes ultimate)

```
[su_column] content [/su_column]
[su_column] content [/su_column]
[su_column] content [/su_column]
<p> content </p>

[su_column] content [/su_column]
[su_column] content [/su_column]
[su_column] content [/su_column]
<p> content </p>

[su_column] content [/su_column]
[su_column] content [/su_column]
[su_column] content [/su_column]
<p> content </p>
```

it would constantly misalign, easily solved by wrapping the blocks 
    [su_row]
      [su_columns] ......
    [/su_row]

full code is in comment below

images can be set to 250px width and it'll come out looking pretty nice like this: http://focallocal.org/activities/

sure this is all pretty simple, but the downvotes i received for asking for help on this topic got me blocked from asking new questions so i thought i'd post the solution in case any other newbies like me have the same issue.

Comment: Could you provide a visualization of what exactly is wrong and what your objective is? Like a simple wireframe illustrating what is wrong and how you would like things laid out? I'm having a little trouble deciphering what the exact issue is.

Comment: the issue was when one column was longer than the others it would mess up the text below it. i just solved it by adding a row

`
[su_row]
[su_column] content [/su_column]
[su_column] content [/su_column]
[su_column] content [/su_column]
[/su_row]`

`<p> content </p>`

`[su_row]
[su_column] content [/su_column]
[su_column] content [/su_column]
[su_column] content [/su_column]
[/su_row]`

`<p> content </p>`

`[su_row]
[su_column] content [/su_column]
[su_column] content [/su_column]
[su_column] content [/su_column]
[/su_row]`

`<p> content </p>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for looking. i just solved it by adding a row around each column

```
[su_row]
[su_column] content [/su_column]
[su_column] content [/su_column]
[su_column] content [/su_column]
[/su_row]

<p> content </p> 

[su_row]
[su_column] content [/su_column]
[su_column] content [/su_column]
[su_column] content [/su_column]
[/su_row]

<p> content </p>

[su_row]
[su_column] content [/su_column]
[su_column] content [/su_column]
[su_column] content [/su_column]
[/su_row]

<p> content </p>
```